# Using variables in UML multiplicities

Tags: uml

I was running a tutorial today, and a we were designing a Class diagram to model a road system. One of the constraints of the system is that any one segment of road has a maximum capacity; once reached, no new vehicles can enter the segment.

When drawing the class diagram, can I use `capacity` as one of the multiplicities? This way, instead of having `0..*` vehicles on a road segment, I can have `0..capacity` vehicles.

I had a look at ISO 1905-1 for inspiration, and I thought that what I want is similar to what they've called a 'multiplicity element'. In the standard, it states:

> If the Multiplicity is associated with an element whose notation is a text string (such as an attribute, etc.), the multiplicity string will be placed within square brackets ([]) as part of that text string. Figure 9.33 shows two multiplicity strings as part of attribute specifications within a class symbol. -- section 9.12

However, in the examples it gives, they don't seem to employ this feature in the way I expected - they annotate association links rather than replace the multiplicities.

I would rather get a definitive answer for the students in question, rather than make a guess based on the standard, so I ask here: has anyone else faced this issue? How did you overcome it?

Comment: Hi@seefin!upvote for a very good question
Could you please drop a link of the tutorial I also interested in modelling  road system?

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately, there isn't a link - I'm a tutor here at uni, and it was a question from a student during the lab. Sorry I couldn't be more help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the UML specification you can use a `ValueSpecification` for lower and upper bounds of a multiplicity element. And a `ValueSpecification` can be an expression. So in theory it must be possible although  the correct expression will be more complex. Indeed it mixes design and instance level.

In such a case it is more usual to use a constraint like this:

[UML multiplicity constraint http://app.genmymodel.com/engine/xaelis/roads.jpg](http://app.genmymodel.com/genmymodel?clonedProject=_te-V8OhlEDCondeuhK_Zpw)

Comment: Please, what do you mean by"it mixes design and instance level"?BTW,Which tool you use to create this diagram? is it free?

Comment: It mixes design and instance level, because the value of the capacity will be known at runtime (instance level) although the multiplicity is defined on the type itself (design level). So the correction expression will mixes types and instance values.

Comment: The tool I use is GenMyModel http://www.genmymodel.com and yes it is free and full online (works on Linux, Mac, Windows). You can click on the diagram above to make a copy of the model into GenMyModel.

Comment: Does GenMyModel fully implement UML specification?which version of specification?
I have noticed that there is no data type model element in the palette for creating a new data type?how that can be managed?

Comment: GenMyModel fully implement the UML specification, currently the 2.2 version. Not all elements are yet available in the palette, but the GMM team is working hard and new diagrams and more model elements (including data type) will be added very soon.

Comment: That's ever so slightly disappointing - it would be a handy notation to have, so we don't have notes everywhere! Thanks for your answer, you have explained well.

Comment: I just think. In such a case you could used UML templates. If capacity of a segment is known at instanciation and never changed at runtime, capacity can be a parameter of a templateable element. It is like generic in Java or template in C++.

Comment: BTW: Why is a Vehicle part of a Segment. I would think a Segment may own a Vehicle instead, right?